# Container for mutable data structure

Tags: data-structures

Faced a confusing question today, which container would best suited for storing a mutable data structure as an entry?

Like map, set, tree, list, or an array?

Comment: That really depends on what you intend to do with that data? The main difference between a tree and a set is not "what does one datum look like" but rather "how is all the data organized"

Comment: In python, if you try to put an item of a mutable type directly into a structure of builtin type `set`, you'll get an error message "Mutable types are not hashable". But this can be worked around in different ways and is not a problem at all in some other languages. For instance, in C and C++, you can hold pointers to your mutable data rather than holding the data directly; so it really doesn't matter whether the data is mutable or not.

Comment: I would like to just store the data in a container. So which data structure will be the best? There was no extra information provided in the question I faced, so I am confused.